# call status in at command

Tags: c#, at-command

I am able to dial a gsm modem with at command "atd". But failed to detect the status (i.e. whether the dialed number is ringing or something else). Here is my code-

code for dialing-

```
ModemPort.WriteLine("atd" + number + ";\r\n");
```

Code for getting the status-

```
private void ModemPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string RcvdData = ModemPort.ReadLine(); 
}
```

The variable RcvdData contains only the following string-

```
^ORIG:1,0
^CONF:1
```

I am using huawei e1550 modem.

Any help?

Comment: What library are you using ? Or is `ModemPort` some .NET namespace I do not know about ?

Comment: ModemPort is an instance of SerialPort class.

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is in the stream and not in the input buffer ? `ReadLine` only looks in the buffer, not the stream. Try `ReadExisting` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting(v=vs.110).aspx